# Python 2-dimensional array is behaving strangely

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I've been attempting to port a program I've written in C++ to Python. Specifically, it is a program for generating heightmaps which can be exported to 3D models, and which ideally, when viewed, would look like realistic terrain.

The HeightMap class wraps a two-dimensional array of float values. For now I've kept it as integers because it prints nicer, and I haven't had a chance to implement any other features. The glitch I'm having is that when I call set(self, x, y, value), which simply sets the value at x, y to value, with the code "self.rows[y][x] = value", it seems to change the entire column, visiting each member of self.rows and setting the xth member of that array to value.

Here is my code. I am about 90% sure the mistake is somewhere in the 2-array's initialization.

```
def filledArray(length, value) :
    result = []
    for i in range(1, length) :
        result.append(value)
    return result

def resizeArray(array, newLength, nullValue) :
    if newLength == len(array) :
        return array
    result = []
    for i in range(0, newLength) :
        if i < len(array) :
            result.append(array[i])
        else :
            result.append(nullValue)
    return result

class HeightMap:
    """A class that wraps a 2D array for generating height maps"""
    def __init__(self) :
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0
        self.rows = []

    def __init__(self, initWidth, initHeight) :
        self.clear(initWidth, initHeight);

    def clear(self, initWidth, initHeight) :
        self.width = initWidth
        self.height = initHeight
        self.rows = filledArray(initHeight, filledArray(initWidth, 0))

    def setHeight(self, newHeight) :
        if self.height == newHeight :
            return
        self.rows = resizeArray(self.rows, newHeight, filledArray(self.width, 0))

    def setWidth(self, newWidth) :
        if self.width == newWidth :
            return
        for i in range(0, len(self.rows)) :
            self.rows[i] = resizeArray(self.rows[i], newWidth, 0);
        self.width = newWidth

    def get(self, x, y) :
        return self.rows[y][x]

    def set(self, x, y, value) :
        self.rows[y][x] = value

    def add(self, x, y, value) :
        self.rows[y][x] += value

    def multiply(self, x, y, value) :
        self.rows[y][x] *= value
```

Comment: This is crazy, python is a high-level language so you should just use a `numpy` array.  Write wrappers around the array interface if necessary.  It will be much faster and much less error-prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call `filledArray(initHeight, filledArray(initWidth, 0))` the second argument is passed by reference (this is always the case with python objects). Inside `filledArray` you need to make a copy of `value` for each. This will require adding a little bit of additional logic to your function, something along the lines of:

```
if type(value) == list:
   value = list(value)
```

Or you could do the slightly less pythonic:

```
type(value)(value)
```

to create a copy.